# CSS Grid, tamaño de un contenedor

Tags: css, css-grid-layout

En CSS grid habrá una opción en la que en vez de declarar cuántas columnas o filas abarque un contenedor, mas bien esto sea impuesto como de forma dinámica? por ejemplo, en vez de declarar que un div esté posicionado de la fila 2 a la 5:

```
#contenedor{
   grid-row: 2 / 3;
   grid-column: 2 / 5;
}
```

declarar que se posicione en la fila 2, o cualquier fila o columna, y abarque cuantas filas dependiendo del tamaño del contenedor?

Comment: ¿Buscás una respuesta solo con CSS o puede incluir JS?

Comment: Buscaba solo con CSS, pero si es ambas mejor